# ServiceBase.Run and memory space

Tags: c#, .net, windows, memory, service

I am running starting a service and all is good.
But a question is in my head

When I run:

ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun.ToArray());

I guess I have to say first that the list of ServicesToRun is a collection of objects, all derived from the ServiceBase class, they all do the "same" task for different clients.

Each of the classes, get succesffuly started. 
So far no problem.
but my question is.

Will every instance of ServiceToRUn have it's own memory space?
as the services that are in the array, have some static variables (and that can not be changed)

If they don't run on a different memory space I can "wrap" by starting:
 a) process (using an .exe)
 b) start a svchost (if i knew how to start it properly)

will b) be possible?

thanks

Comment: At a *wild* guess you're talking about windows services implemented in some .NET language. Please reconsider the tags and edit your question to give people a *clue* about what technologies you're talking about.

Answer (score -1):

> Will every instance of ServiceToRUn have it's own memory space?

Yes. As in every instance of a class has it's own memory.

No, as it does not start other processes. it just instructs a service to start.

b is possible - not sure why youare bothere though, given how much memory modern servers have. Note that nothing will optimize memory consumption at the end. Multi exe - mutli servicehosts - are less efficient due to higher runtime memory allocations (one per process).

At the end I even question why you have multiple services. You say one per client - that has a smell like "not made a service that can handle multiple clients".

Comment: :) thanks for your answer.
I used wrongly the word client, what is actually starting a scheduler (implementation of Timer class) that will service different databases. 

So as i understand your answer, 

I don't have to wrap anything neither to create an .exe nor use a svchost 
as the static variables (when they are read from the db)  WON'T CLASH OR OVERRIDE each other on each implementation of the ServiceBase. 

Is that correct my understanding?

Comment: @"As in every instance of a class has it's own memory". The instance data yes. Static things will be shared. The OP explicitly asked about statics. -1

Comment: ow.... so static content will be overriden :( ... 
Time to wrap? best option ?

a) convert the Timers to .exe ? and start it with create process?
b) start an svchost and use a .dll

Comment: c: remove static. The servie was basicalyl written in a bad way - fix that.

Comment: As i stated... static can not be removed at all as is a load of code involved. thanks for your answers

Comment: Well, then qha about putting every service in a separate APPDOMAIN? That is less heavy than a process.

Comment: @TomTom I will inspect on that. sounds way to go

Comment: I use it for a lot of things I Want isolated and unloadable (because you can unload assemblies from memory if you close an appdomain) but do not want separate processes (heavy, slow communication).